# YouTube Video height doubled on iPhone and iPad

Tags: youtube, mobile-safari

Embedded YouTube videos are displaying at double their specified height on mobile Safari. The dimensions are correct on a desktop. Here's an example, you'll see what I mean:

http://whinyliberal.com/throwback-thursday-crazy-libs-mourning-loss-of-a-tree/

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Developers are tracking this problem here:

http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/861d5605093fdd7b

Answer (score 0):

At first I was using a iOS detect script to apply a height of 1px, but then I found this much simpler solution:

Add scrolling="no" in the iframe declaration.